# C# regular expression not considering Line feed

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regular expression as:

```
Regex regExpForPurchaseIndent = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^(([0-9]*[a-zA-Z]*)*[, ]*)*$";);
```

The string `"PRFA1223,JIBD122,\nPIHFU1343"` makes the application hang at the `if` statement

```
if (!regExpForPurchaseIndent.IsMatch(newAsset.PurchaseIndent))
{
       //Print the string is not correct
}
```

Now I know `RegEx` treats '\n' as a special case. But when my expression doesn't have a '\n' detector, how can it hang? It should rather say the string is wrong, I am not able to figure where i am going wrong.
Please someone let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is your regex pattern. Will the elements you are trying to match always have letters followed by numbers and be separated by comma and optional whitespace? If so, this might give you what you want (although it could be more refined than this); `^([a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*[, ]*)*$`?

You can use a regex tester to help you, I like this one http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Answer (score 1):

Do you use:

```
string s = "PRFA1223,JIBD122,\nPIHFU1343";
OR
string s = @"PRFA1223,JIBD122,\nPIHFU1343";
```

Please try both.

About the code hang, I never saw c# hang before, please give more code

also try

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(newAsset.PurchaseIndent, @"^(([0-9]*[a-zA-Z]*)*[, ]*)*$"))
```

Btw, `([0-9]*[a-zA-Z]*)*` does not make sense

Answer (score 1):

It does not hang, it does take a very long time because of your very nested quantifiers. The regex has just not finished.

You should refactor your regex, try e.g. this:

```
Regex regExpForPurchaseIndent = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]*(?:[, ]*[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]*)*$");
```